# Clustering in AEM

Tags: aem, sling

I am facing an error, which is something peculiar. I am using AEM 5.6.1.

I have 2 author instances(a1 and a2) and both are in cluster. We are performing tar optimization on the instances daily between 2a.m. - 5a.m.(London Timezone). Now, in the error.log of a2, I am seeing the below error everyday in the above mentioned time:

> 419 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.sling.discovery.impl.cluster.ClusterViewServiceImpl getEstablishedView: the existing established view does not incude the enter code herelocal instance yet! Assming isolated mode.

Now, I did some research on this and has come to know that, AEM users `ClusterViewServiceImpl.java` for clustering. And in that, the below mentioned code snippet is basically failing:

```
EstablishedClusterView clusterViewImpl = new EstablishedClusterView(
                    config, view, getSlingId());
            boolean foundLocal = false;
            for (Iterator<InstanceDescription> it = clusterViewImpl
                    .getInstances().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                InstanceDescription instance = it.next();
                if (instance.isLocal()) {
                    foundLocal = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundLocal) {
                return clusterViewImpl;
            } else {
                logger.info("getEstablishedView: the existing established view does not incude the local instance yet! Assuming isolated mode.");
                return getIsolatedClusterView();
            }
```

Can someone help me to understand more in depth regarding the same. Does it mean that, the clustering is not properly working? What can be the possible impacts because of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a classic case of split brain.

Clustering authors is not a good approach and has been disfavoured in future versions of AEM, as the authors often get out of sync when they can't talk to each other for whatever reason, usually temporarily network related. Believe me, they are sensitive.

When communication drops, the slave thinks it no longer has a master, and claims to be the master itself. When that occurs, and communication is re-established the damage has been done as there is no recovery mechanism.

At best, only ever allow users to connect to the primary author and have the secondary author as a High Availability server.

Better still, set up replication from the primary author that everyone writes to, and have it auto replicate on write to the secondary backup author.

Hope that helps.